# Issue on services php code

Tags: php, mysql, json, dictionary

I have create the services in php,but i faced on some issue,here it is i implemented my code

```
 <?php
include("db.php");
$month=10;
$year=date("Y");
$sq=mysql_query('select * from city where id=1 ORDER BY city ASC');
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($sq)){
$id = $re1['id'];
$city = $re1['city'];
$city_id = $re1['id'];
echo '{ <br>"'.$city.'" : [ <br>'; 

$sql='select * from price where month="'.$month.'" and year="'.$year.'" and city="'.$id.'" ORDER BY day ASC';
$sql2=mysql_query($sql);
while($re2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
echo  '{ <br>';
echo '"date" : "'.$re2["day"].'-'.$re2["month"].'-'.$re2["year"].'",<br>';

 if($re2['price']==''){ echo "Price : -- , <br>";}
else{
echo '"Price" : "'.$re2["price"].'" <br>';
}
echo '}, <br>';
}
echo ']<br>}';
}
?>
```

The response json format like this.

```
{
"Ahmedabad" : [
{
"date" : "1-10-2014",
"Price" : "353"
},
{
"date" : "2-10-2014",
"Price" : "353"
},
{
"date" : "3-10-2014",
"Price" : "327"
},
]
}
```

But in json format ending dictionary how can remove this `,` . Can you please suggest me.

Comment: Build your output as array and use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) function. Building JSON manually is unnecessary and will be hard to maintain.

Comment: The `mysql_` library is deprecated and will be removed from a future version of PHP. Use an alternative like PDO or MySQLi, and use parameterisation to protect yourself from security problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't have `<br>` in the JSON response unless this response is just for show and not for actual use.

In order to remove that `,` at the end you need to have each "line" created in a variable you can edit and not just echo the line.

Here is some code that will accomplish that:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$month=10;
$year=date("Y");
$sq=mysql_query('select * from city where id=1 ORDER BY city ASC');
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($sq)){
$id = $re1['id'];
$city = $re1['city'];
$city_id = $re1['id'];
echo '{
"'.$city.'" : [
'; 

$sql='select * from price where month="'.$month.'" and year="'.$year.'" and city="'.$id.'" ORDER BY day ASC';
$sql2=mysql_query($sql);
while($re2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
    $line = '{
    ';

    $line.= '"date" : "'.$re2["day"].'-'.$re2["month"].'-'.$re2["year"].'",
    ';

    if($re2['price']=='')
    { 
        $line.= "Price : -- ,
        ";
    }
    else
    {
        $line.= '"Price" : "'.$re2["price"].'"
        ';
    }
    $line.= '},';
    echo $line;
}
$line = substr($line,0,-1);
echo ']
}';
}
?>
```

You should use PHP built in JSON formatting functions like [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

In order to make a good JSON response you need to work with data correctly to avoid formating errors.

So this code is a much better use of PHP and MySQL:

```
<?php
include("db.php");
$month=10;
$year=date("Y");
$sq=mysql_query('select * from city where id=1 ORDER BY city ASC');
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($sq)){
    $id = $re1['id'];
    $city = $re1['city'];
    $city_id = $re1['id'];

    $sql='select * from price where month="'.$month.'" and year="'.$year.'" and city="'.$id.'" ORDER BY day ASC';
    $sql2=mysql_query($sql);
    while($re2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
        // create each line in the city
        $line["date"] = $re2["day"].'-'.$re2["month"].'-'.$re2["year"];

        if($re2['price']=='')
        { 
            $line["Price"] = "--";
        }
        else
        {
            $line["Price"] = $re2["price"];
        }

        // add the line to the city
        $cities[$city][] = $line;
    }
}
// encode to json
json_encode($cities);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it.  I am now adding a comma at the start of the date/Price block, at every date/Price combo except for the first one (checked by the new $ct variable).

```
 <?php
include("db.php");
$month=10;
$year=date("Y");
$sq=mysql_query('select * from city where id=1 ORDER BY city ASC');
while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($sq)){
  $id = $re1['id'];
  $city = $re1['city'];
  $city_id = $re1['id'];
  echo '{ <br>"'.$city.'" : [ <br>'; 

  $sql='select * from price where month="'.$month.'" and year="'.$year.'" and city="'.$id.'" ORDER BY day ASC';
  $sql2=mysql_query($sql);
  $ct = 0;
    while($re2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){
      if ($ct > 0) { echo ', ';}
      ct++;
      echo  '{ <br>';
      echo '"date" : "'.$re2["day"].'-'.$re2["month"].'-'.$re2["year"].'",<br>';

      if($re2['price']==''){ echo "Price : -- , <br>";}
      else{
        echo '"Price" : "'.$re2["price"].'" <br>';
      }
      echo '}<br>';
    }
    echo ']<br>}';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
include("db.php");
$month=10;
$year=date("Y");

$sq=mysql_query('select * from city where id=1 ORDER BY city ASC');

$city=array();

while($re1=mysql_fetch_array($sq)){
    $city['city'] = $re1['city'];

    $sql='select * from price where month="'.$month.'" and year="'.$year.'" and city="'.$id.'" ORDER BY         day ASC';
    $sql2=mysql_query($sql);
    while($re2=mysql_fetch_array($sql2)){

    $city['city'] = array("date" => $re2["day"].'-'.$re2["month"].'-'.$re2["year"];

        if($re2['price']==''){ 
            $city['city'] = array('price'=>'--'); 
        }else{
            $city['city'] = array('price'=>$re2["price"]);
        }
    }
}
echo json_encode($city);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Rather than answer your question with exactly what to change to fix your code, here's a refactored version of your code with notes that I would have loved to have had when I started programming in PHP. Hope there's something in here for you:

```
$month = 10;
$year = date('Y');

// 1. You can get the data you're after in a single query using a LEFT JOIN.
//    In your original code you run one database query for every city, which
//    quickly slows down the program as you add more cities. This change is
//    mostly for keeping the code clean in this case, but in practice it's
//    good to avoid unnecessary back and forth with the database.
//
// 2. The MySQL DATE data type opens up a lot of functionality in your queries
//    that isn't available when storing day, month and year in separate columns.
//            
// 3. The mysql_* functions are deprecated and no longer exist in PHP 5.5.0,
//    so you ideally shouldn't be using them (see the red box in the docs):
//    
//        http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php
//    
//    I've opted to demo PDO with a parameterised query as I like it, but you
//    could use the mysqli_* functions instead. The following pretends that
//    $connection is an instance of PDO. The variable `$stmt` stands for
//    'statement'. Further info on PDO:
//
//        http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php
//        http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers
//
$stmt = $connection->prepare(
    'SELECT
        city.name AS city,
        price.price,
        DATE_FORMAT(price.date, '%d-%m-%Y') AS date
    FROM city
    LEFT JOIN price ON price.city_id = city.id
    WHERE MONTH(price.date) = :month AND YEAR(price.date) = :year
    ORDER BY DAY(price.date) ASC'
);

$stmt->bindValue(':month', $month);
$stmt->bindValue(':year', $year);

$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// This short array syntax is valid in PHP 5.4 and higher.
// If you're using 5.3 or lower, `[]` would be `array()`
$output = [];

foreach ($results as $row) {
    $output[$row['city']] = [
        'date' => $row['date'],
        'price' => $row['price'] ?: '--'
    ];
}

json_encode($output);
```

General notes:

- **The database is really powerful:** in many cases it's simpler and faster to organise your data in a query than in your PHP code.
- **Keep it simple:** try to achieve things in the simplest way possible (eg. `json_encode` instead of manually building a JSON string). If something you're trying to do seems overly difficult, there may be a better way to solve the problem.
- **Love your code:** whitespace, indentation, and giving variables meaningful names will greatly improve the readability of your code. You'll thank yourself (or someone reading your code will) a year or two later.